# relative absolute path perl

Tags: perl

Following directory setup:

```
/dira/dirb
/dira/dirb/myprog.pl
```

`/dira/dirb/testa/myfilesdir` Contains the following files

```
/dira/dirb/testa/myfilesdir/file1.txt
/dira/dirb/testa/myfilesdir/file2.txt
```

Current dir:

```
/dir/dirb

./myprog.pl  -p testa/myfilesdir
```

Cycle through files

```
while (my $file_to_proc = readdir(DIR)) {
...

$file_to_proc = file1.txt
$file_to_proc = file2.txt
```

what I want is

```
$myfile = /dira/dirb/testa/myfilesdir/file1.txt
$myfile = /dira/dirb/testa/myfilesdir/file2.txt
```

Tried a few different perl module (CWD rel2abs) but it is using current directory. I can not use current directory because input could be relative or absolute path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use module `File::Spec`. Here an example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Spec;

for ( @ARGV ) { 
    chomp;
    if ( -f $_ ) { 
        printf qq[%s\n], File::Spec->rel2abs( $_ );
    }   
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl mydir/*
```

And it will print absolute paths of files.

---

**UPDATED** with a more efficient program. Thanks to **TLP**'s suggestions.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Spec;

for ( @ARGV ) { 
    if ( -f ) {
        print File::Spec->rel2abs( $_ ), "\n";
    }   
}
```

Comment: `chomp` seems redundant here. `-f` will test `$_` if the argument is omitted, which also makes `$_` redundant. I would further argue that this is a redundant use of `printf`.

Comment: @TLP: Thank you. I've updated the answer with your suggestions. Much better now but I left the original program

Comment: I changed program add used File::Basename File::Find and combination. Did help point me to new module. thx